# jQuery plugin/library for this table to simplify code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

https://jsfiddle.net/51Le6o06/48/

please take a look at the jsfiddle the code is getting to complicated and my functions aren't working correctly.

can anyone tell me what I could use instead of standard jQuery and javascript to make this easier to build (with a show more style pagination method).

I need to sort, filter and page existing html as in the jsfiddle.

thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.filter-gift').each(filterItems);
});

function filterItems(e) {
    var items = [];
    var table = '';
    tableId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('tag')

      var listItems = "";
        listItems += "<option value=''> -Select- </option>";
        $('div[tag="' + tableId + '"] table.internalActivities .information').each(function (i) {
            var itm = $(this)[0].innerText;
            if ($.inArray(itm, items) == -1) {
                items.push($(this)[0].innerText);
                listItems += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + $(this)[0].innerText + "</option>";
            }
        });

    $('div[tag="' + tableId+ '"] .filter-gift').html(listItems);

    $('.filter-gift').change(function () {
    if($(this).val()!= "") {
        var tableIdC = $(this).parent().parent().attr('tag');

        var text = $('div[tag="' + tableIdC + '"] select option:selected')[0].text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r| |)/gm, "");;
            $('div[tag="' + tableIdC + '"] .product-information-row').each(function (i) {
                if ($(this).text().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r| |)/gm, "") == text) {
                    $(this).show();
                    $(this).prev().show();
                    $(this).next().show();
                }
                else {
                    $(this).hide();
                    $(this).prev().hide();
                    $(this).next().hide();
                }
            }); 
            } else {
            $(this).parent().parent().find('table tr').show();
            }
        });     
}


jQuery.fn.sortPaging = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
        pageRows: 2
    };
    var settings = $.extend(true, defaults, options);
    return this.each(function() {

        var container = $(this);
        var tableBody = container.find('.internalActivities > tbody');
        var dataRows = [];
        var currentPage = 1;
        var maxPages = 1;
        var buttonMore = container.find('.seeMoreRecords');
        var buttonLess = container.find('.seeLessRecords');
        var buttonFree = container.find('.filter-free');
        var tableRows = [];
        var maxFree = 0;
        var filterFree = buttonFree.is(':checked');
        function displayRows() {
            tableBody.empty();
            var displayed = 0;
            $.each(dataRows, function(i, ele) {
                if( !filterFree || (filterFree && ele.isFree) ) {
                    tableBody.append(ele.thisRow).append(ele.nextRow);
                    displayed++;
                    if( displayed >= currentPage*settings.pageRows ) {
                        return false;
                    };
                };
            });
        };
        function checkButtons() {
            buttonLess.toggleClass('element_invisible', currentPage<=1);
            buttonMore.toggleClass('element_invisible', filterFree ? currentPage>=maxFreePages : currentPage>=maxPages);
        };
        function showMore() {
            currentPage++;
            displayRows();
            checkButtons();
        };
        function showLess() {
            currentPage--;
            displayRows();
            checkButtons();
        };
        function changedFree() {
            filterFree = buttonFree.is(':checked');
            if( filterFree && currentPage>maxFreePages ) {
                currentPage=maxFreePages;
            };
            displayRows();
            checkButtons();
        };

        tableBody.find('.product-data-row').each(function(i, j) {
            var thisRow = $(this);
            var nextRow = thisRow.next();
            var amount = parseFloat(thisRow.find('.amount').text().replace(/£/, ''));
            var isFree = thisRow.find('.free').length;
            maxFree += isFree;
            dataRows.push({
                amount: amount,
                thisRow: thisRow,
                nextRow: nextRow,
                isFree: isFree
            });
        })

        dataRows.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.amount - b.amount;
        });
        maxPages = Math.ceil(dataRows.length/settings.pageRows);
        maxFreePages = Math.ceil(maxFree/settings.pageRows);

        tableRows = tableBody.find("tr");

        buttonMore.on('click', showMore);
        buttonLess.on('click', showLess);
        buttonFree.on('change', changedFree);

        displayRows();
        checkButtons();

    })

};

$('.sort_paging').sortPaging();
```

Answer (score 2):

The best solution when it comes to tables with all the filter, sorting, pagination features and much more is one and only.

[jQuery Datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom.html)

Just check out the link, It's Easy and Highly Customizable.

Comment: I checked it out but it doesn't seem to have the show more pagination style or does it?

Comment: Yes there is no show more/ show less functionality, But it can be achieved by slight modifications in existing options available in data-tables.

"simple" pagination with "Next" and "Previous" buttons.          

Link: https://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType

For changing labels from "Next" and "Previous" to "Show more" and "Show less", available methods are.

Changing "Next" label : https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.paginate.next

Changing "Previous" label: https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.paginate.previous

Hope it helps !

Comment: do you think (in your opinion) i would be best off trashing my current code and trying to build this table with datatables?

Comment: I do strongly recommend it as i have used it in most complex scenarios and it works like charm. Of course there is learning curve to it. But once you have it rolling there is no stopping you.

Comment: how hard would it be to convert this table to data tables?

Comment: It will be an intermediate stuff, we can rate it 5 out of 10.

Comment: I suppose it wont be as hard as what I've been trying to do lol

Comment: with datatables can you build table filters like this http://www.buymobiles.net/samsung/galaxy-s7-black

Comment: Of-course, you can build anything and in any layout using datatables, I  have worked on so many complex website with filters combinations and lot more features, If you can spend some time with datatables, you will not regret.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use this jquery plug-in [DataTables](https://datatables.net/)